# exception on drawing polygon using java swing

Tags: swing

hey i am writing a simple java swing program. but when i draw the frame with polygons drawn from a for loop an exception occurs.

the for loop:

```
for (int i=0;i<k;i++)
  { x= 100; y= 100;
  for(int j=0;j<k;j++)
  { if (cell[i][j]==0) break;
   if(i % 2 !=0)
    { p = new Polygon();
     for (int h = 0; h < 6; i++)
            p.addPoint((int) (x + 50 * Math.cos(h * 2 * Math.PI / 6)),(int) (y + 50 * Math.sin(h * 2 * Math.PI / 6)));

         g.drawPolygon(p);
    }    
   x+=75;
  }
  y+=45;
  }

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2834)
    at java.awt.Polygon.addPoint(Polygon.java:279)
    at freqnew.paintComponent(freqnew.java:44)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1027)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:864)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1036)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:864)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1036)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:564)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:864)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5129)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:277)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1213)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1013)
    at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:21)

    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:60)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:97)
    at java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:1762)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:810)

    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:714)

    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.seqPaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:694)
    at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(SystemEventQueueUtilities.java:128)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)

    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)

    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

tried to increase java heap but my method from command promt seems to be wrong.
tried  : java -Xms128m -Xmx256m

plz help me asap.

Comment: Unless there is a typo in the question's code, this looks like a simple index iteration error.  Notice that your `Polygon`-building loop says `for (int h = 0; h < 6; i++)`.  You're building infinite-vertex `Polygon`s.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is incomplete and scrambled. Are you sure you don't have a loop terminating condition that can't occur? (i.e. an infinite loop). How many polygons are you drawing?

You could put in some logging to verify that the code does what you expect.

You could put in an early termination to the loop and use OS facilities to check memory usage to see if a leak (i.e. pack-ratting) is occurring.

Comment: sorry the thats not my code..it got scrambled.. it goes this way:

Comment: for (int i=0;i<k;i++)
 {   x= 100; y= 100;
  for(int j=0;j<k;j++)
  { if (cell[i][j]==0) break;
   if(i % 2 !=0)
    { 
     p = new Polygon();
     for (int h = 0; h < 6; i++)
            p.addPoint((int) (x + 50 * Math.cos(h * 2 * Math.PI / 6)),(int) (y + 50 * Math.sin(h * 2 * Math.PI / 6)));

         g.drawPolygon(p);
    }    
   x+=75;
  }
  y+=45;
  }

Comment: Comments don't format well, what I do is edit the question and post the code at the end after inserting a horizontal line and the word "EDIT" - then readers can work out what happened. In this case you could just correct the question and add a comment or a note at the end of the question like "Edit: scrambled code corrected".